# Join another table then show max from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to sql so struggling a lot here.

I have 2 tables, Customer, and Transaction

**Transaction**

| tID | cID | carID | eID | tDate | PickupDate | ReturnDate | Amount_Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Customer**

| cID | fName | lName | Address | Postcode | email | DOB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I need to show all Customer information for the customer with the highest Amount_Due.

I think I have the first part correct but cannot get the Join working correctly.

```
SELECT c.cID
    ,c.fName
    ,c.lName
    ,c.Address
    ,c.Postcode
    ,c.email
    ,c.DOB
    ,[Transaction].Amount_Due
FROM Customer c, [Transaction]
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(Amount_Due) AS Amount_Due
    FROM [Transaction]
    GROUP BY Amount_Due
) t
    ON c.cID = t.cID
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: You want customer with the highest amount due - that would be just 1 record (unless there are ties)? Maybe: `SELECT TOP 1 Transaction.*, Customer.* FROM Transaction INNER JOIN Customer on Transaction.cID = Customer.cID ORDER BY Amount_Due DESC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one method of solving this if I understand it correctly. e.g:

```
SELECT
    c.cID
  , c.fName
  , c.lName
  , c.Address
  , c.Postcode
  , c.email
  , c.DOB
  , t.Amount_Due
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                cID
              , MAX(Amount_Due) AS Amount_Due
            FROM [Transaction]
            GROUP BY cID
            ) t ON c.cID = t.cID
WHERE t.Amount_Due = (SELECT MAX(Amount_Due) FROM transactions)
```

or:

```
with cte as (
select cID, amount_due, max(Amount_Due) over(partition by 1) as max_amount_due from transactions
)
select
*
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN cte on c.cID = cte.cID
               and cte.amount_due = cte.max_amount_due
```

Comment: Your first query works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.cID
,c.fName
,c.lName
,c.Address
,c.Postcode
,c.email
,c.DOB
,t.Amount_Due
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT cID, MAX(Amount_Due) AS Amount_Due
    FROM [Transaction]
    GROUP BY cID
) t
    ON c.cID = t.cID
```

Comment: Was this helpful?